# MS Word VBA: Fixing a run-time 5487 Error

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have been working for several days now on this same bit of code trying to get the run-time 5487 error to go away but have not had any luck. I would appreciate any help I could get on this. The error occurs one line:

```
ActiveDocument.SaveAs Fullname, fileformat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False.
```

The file path name comes out as `E:\assessment_rubrics\Program  Art-Teaching Certif BA BS
.docx` when I debug.print it.

```
Function cvtstr(strIn As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Const str = "/|?*<>"":"
    cvtstr = strIn
    For i = 1 To Len(str)
    cvtstr = Replace(cvtstr, Mid$(str, i, 1), " ")
Next i
End Function


Sub Splitter()

' splitter Macro

' Macro created by Doug Robbins to save each letter created by a mailmergeas a separate file.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Program As String
Dim DocName As String
Dim Letters As Integer, Counter As Integer
Dim file_name, extension, Fullname, filepath, Mask As String

Letters = ActiveDocument.Sections.Count
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
Counter = 1
While Counter < Letters
'program =  ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("Program_Outcomes_PlanReport_Name").Value
DocName = "Reports" & LTrim$(str$(Counter))  'Generic name of document
ActiveDocument.Sections.First.Range.Cut
Documents.Add
Selection.Paste
'ActiveDocument.Sections(2).PageSetup.SectionStart = wdSectionContinuous

file_name = cvtstr(ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text)
file_name = Left(file_name, Len(file_name) - 1)
extension = ".docx"
DocName = "E:\assessment_rubrics\" & filename & file_name
Fullname = DocName & extension

Debug.Print Fullname
Debug.Print file_name

ActiveDocument.SaveAs Fullname, fileformat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False

ActiveWindow.Close
Counter = Counter + 1
Wend

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have write permissions for your E: ?

Comment: I'm actually not sure how to check that, its just a flash drive I save all of my work to

Comment: What happens if you change that line to just `ActiveDocument.SaveAs Fullname` ?

Comment: It still gives the file permission error. I tried to change the path to just a folder on my desktop and that still gave the permission error

Comment: I cannot see where `filename` is declared.  Is it any empty var?  Try adding `Option Explicit` to the top of this module.  That statement will prevent you from using vars without first declaring them (a source of tricky errors).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out the problem by going to https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other/word-visual-basic-code/f1a23c49-da37-4974-9287-b224644ae617?auth=1. It turns out that my file name contained a paragraph mark at the end of it so by using `file_name = Replace(file_name, Chr(13), "")` I was able to resolve the issue!